# Combine results based on condition during group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

Mongo query generated out of java code:

```
{ 
    "pipeline": [{
        "$match": {
            "Id": "09cd9a5a-85c5-4948-808b-20a52d92381a"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$result",
            "id": {
                "$first": "$result"
            },
            "labelKey": {
                "$first": {
                    "$ifNull": ["$result",
                    "$result"]
                }
            },
            "value": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Field 'result' can have values like Approved, Rejected, null and "" (empty string). What I am trying to achieve is combining the count of both null and empty together.

[image]

So that the empty string Id will have the count of both null and "", which is equal to 4

Comment: Can you share sample output? what should be the result of query!

Comment: For values of `null` or "empty string" `""` then do something like `{ "$group": { "_id": { "$ifNull": [ "$result", ""] }, ..same accumulators .. } }`. The `$ifNull` would tranpose any `null` values from `$result` in the grouping key to be an "empty string", just like the other values in that field are which you want to "group" them with. If you needed something more elaborate then you could look at `$cond`. But it's basically about testing the `$result` value within the grouping `_id` key and combining where you want to.

Comment: Also note that `$first` or `$last` really should not be used without a `$sort` stage preceding the `$group`. So your code really should include a `$sort` to put things in the expected order first, otherwise there is nothing which actually determines what `$first` actually picks up, and it very possibly would change on subsequent iterations of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure theres a more "proper" way but this is what i could quickly come up with:

```
    [
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$result", 
                "id" : {
                   "$first" : "$result"
                }, 
                "labelKey" : {
                    "$first" : {
                        "$ifNull" : [
                            "$result", 
                            "$result"
                        ]
                    }
                }, 
                "value" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "$cond" : [{
                           $or: [
                              {"$eq": ["$_id", "Approved"]},
                              {"$eq": ["$_id", "Rejected"]},
                           ]}}, 
                        "$_id", 
                        ""
                    ]
                }, 
                "temp" : {
                    "$push" : {
                        "_id" : "$_id", 
                        "labelKey" : "$labelKey"
                    }
                }, 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : "$value"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$temp"
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : "$temp._id", 
                "labelKey": "$temp.labelKey",
                "count" : "$count"
            }
        }
    ], 
);
```

Due to the fact the second group is only on 4 documents tops i don't feel too bad about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

The MongoDB stage $facet lets you run several independent pipelines within the stage of a pipeline, all using the same data. This means that you can run several aggregations with the same preliminary stages, and successive stages.

```
  var queries = [{
    "$match": {
        "Id": "09cd9a5a-85c5-4948-808b-20a52d92381a"
    }
  },{
        $facet: {// 
             "empty": [
             {
                $match : {
                    result : { $in : ['',null]}
                }
             },{
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : null,
                        value : { $sum : 1}
                    }
             }
            ],
             "non_empty": [
             {
                $match : {
                    result : { $nin : ['',null]}
                }
             },{
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : '$result',
                        value : { $sum : 1}
                    }
             }
            ]
         }
     },
     {
      $project: {
       results: {
        $concatArrays: [ "$empty", "$non_empty" ] 
    } 
}
}];
```

Output :

```
{
"results": [{
    "_id": null, 
    "value": 52 // count of both '' and null.
}, {
    "_id": "Approved",
    "value": 83
}, {
    "_id": "Rejected",
    "value": 3661
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the group by like below solved the problem

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$ifNull": ["$result", ""]
        },
        "id": {
            "$first": "$result"
        },
        "labelKey": {
            "$first": {
                "$ifNull": ["$result",
                "$result"]
            }
        },
        "value": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}
```